# CUDA cuMemcpuHtoD vs cuMemcpy2D

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, cuda

Asking it here and not on SO as it seems to be appropriate question for CG.
I am learning [NVIDIA NVENC](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) API.The SDK supplies a sampled called "NvEncoderCudaInterop" .There is a chunk of code which copies YUV plane arrays from CPU to GPU buffers.
This is the code:

```
 // copy luma
 CUDA_MEMCPY2D copyParam;
memset(&copyParam, 0, sizeof(copyParam));
copyParam.dstMemoryType = CU_MEMORYTYPE_DEVICE;
copyParam.dstDevice = pEncodeBuffer->stInputBfr.pNV12devPtr;
copyParam.dstPitch = pEncodeBuffer->stInputBfr.uNV12Stride;
copyParam.srcMemoryType = CU_MEMORYTYPE_HOST;
copyParam.srcHost = yuv[0];
copyParam.srcPitch = width;
copyParam.WidthInBytes = width;
copyParam.Height = height;
__cu(cuMemcpy2D(&copyParam));

// copy chroma

__cu(cuMemcpyHtoD(m_ChromaDevPtr[0], yuv[1], width*height / 4));
__cu(cuMemcpyHtoD(m_ChromaDevPtr[1], yuv[2], width*height / 4));
```

I do understand the rationale behind the procedure.The memory is copied to GPU  for the kernel to process it.What I don't understand is why,in order to copy Y plane, cuMemcpy2D is used and for UV [cuMemcpyHtoD](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MEM_g4d32266788c440b0220b1a9ba5795169.html)?Why Y can't be copied using cuMemcpyHtoD as well?As far as I understand,YUV planes have the same linear memory layout.The only difference is their size.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with NVENC, but it looks as if the `dstPitch` for the Y array is being supplied by the NVENC API, so it might conceivably differ from `srcPitch`, thus requiring the 2D copy instead of a straight memory copy. Not sure why the Y channel would require this where Uand V don't, though.